# How to get AVG from SQLAlchemy Query?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm currently learning SQLAlchemy and I have a Reviews Model which looks like this:

```
class Review(Base):

__tablename__ = "reviews"

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
raw_score = Column(String(150))
score = Column(Float, nullable=False)
summary = Column(String(150), nullable=False)
review = Column(String(1500), nullable=False)
source = Column(String)
product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'), nullable=False)
reviewer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('reviewers.id'), nullable=False)
```

Using SQLAlchemy, I'm able to get all the reviews related to a certain Product and if the Reviewer is not a Critic:

```
    reviews = session.query(Review).join(Review.reviewer).\
         filter(Review.product == product).\
         filter(Reviewer.critic == False).\
         values(Reviewer.critic,
                Reviewer.display_name,
                Review.raw_score,
                Review.score,
                Review.review,
                Review.source)
```

I then attempt to make another query to get me the average of the scores written by critics and non critics:

```
critic_avg = session.query(func.avg(Review.score)).filter(Review.product == product).\
             filter(Reviewer.critic == True)

not_critic_avg =  session.query(func.avg(Review.score)).filter(Review.product == product).\
             filter(Reviewer.critic == False)
```

This, however, does not give me back the expected value, it seems to always give me back the average of scores for the product. It seems like the filter for the Product is working but the Filter for Critic is not.

Expected Non-Critic Average: 2.75

Actual Non-Critic Average: 2.75

(There are no Reviewers who are critics in the DB yet)

Expected Critic Average: 0.00

Actual Critic Average: 2.75

Curious if there's an obvious fault in the above and if there's a more efficient way to tackle this. Could I have addressed this at the same time as when I queried for reviews?

As always, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to join `Reviewer` table, though you have done it properly in previous request:

```
critic_avg = session.query(func.avg(Review.score)).\
    join(Reviewer).\
    filter(Review.product == product).\
    filter(Reviewer.critic == True)
```

**UPD:** Every query constructed in SQLAlchemy produces an SQL statement. You can <s>use [Query.as_scalar()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar) method to</s> just print the actual SQL statement of your query and find an error. In your case the query was something like this:

```sql
SELECT avg(reviews.score) FROM reviews WHERE reviews.reviewer_id = :param_1 AND reviewers.critic = True;
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks so much for pointing out query.as_scalar()

Comment: You can just print any query or expression for that matter, no need to create a scalar subquery first using `as_scalar`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä What a shame, I didn't know about this. Many thanks!